# Wifi direct P2P aplication

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am trying to create a android Wi-Fi Direct (P2P) application. I found this code ([Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi : Message passing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406853/creating-p2p-connections-with-wi-fi-message-passing-issue)) and I'm trying to test it, but when I run the application I can't even find the devices. I believe it is related to the API level (I already tried with 32 and 24) or Android.

When I debug this is what I find:

```
E/test: Discovering Peers Success..
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI Binary is enabled
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI Binary is enabled
E/test: NUMBER OF PEERS AVAILABLE: ----- 0
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x72f2a6d010 disconnect failed
V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType: 0
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/WifiP2pManager: discoverPeers, pid:23887, tid:23887, uid:101
```

These were the devices I tried Samsung M31s, Huawei P20 lite, Huawei P Smart and Xiaomi Mi6.

I already saw this tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p
but this code looks legit.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use another phone to be Service(GO), use the following code:

```
    //first to check your wifi group is already have a GO
    wifiP2pManager.requestGroupInfo(appChannel, new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup wifiP2pGroup) {
            if (wifiP2pGroup != null){
                //if already have a GO, try to remove it, and make this phone tobe the new GO
                wifiP2pManager.removeGroup(appChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //remove success, try tobe the new GO
                        wifiP2pManager.createGroup(appChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                //you are the new GO, can let another phone to start discover you(this phone)
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int i) {
                                //fail tobe the new GO, log the reason
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        //remove fail, log the reason
                    }
                });
            }else {
                //the group doesn't have GO, go ahead tobe the new GO
                wifiP2pManager.createGroup(appChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //you are the new GO, can let another phone to start discover you(this phone)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i) {
                        //fail tobe the new GO, log the reason
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

after tobe the GO, you can let another phone(it will be GC) to start discover you(this phone)

hope my answer will help you~

Comment: thanks for the help, but i tried your code and it's still the same, i still don't see a list of devices i can connect

Comment: @JoãoClara have you open the phone' GPS?

Comment: yes, tested with GPS enable

Comment: @JoãoClara I can provide some example code for you, and i have already test success in two phones: `xiaomi6X (android9)` and  `redmiK40 (android12)` . You can leave your email address or other contact information.

Comment: alright, you can send it to this email: 2201103@my.ipleiria.pt

Comment: did you send? I didn't receive

Comment: you can check you email, i used gMail to send the file to you. @JoãoClara